# Where is command if compiled?

Tags: tcl

I am checking out the source of tcl 8.6.3 and like to see how the byte code works. But I cannot find where is command `if` compiled.

I looked at `tclCompCmds.c`, it has a bunch of commands, such as `break`, `continue`, etc., but I do not see command `if`.

Could you point me where is the compile routine of command `if`?

Comment: Did you try grepping for it? Or asking your IDE to do the search?

Answer (score 0):

It is in `generic/tclCompCmdsGR.c` (function `TclCompileIfCmd()`).

BTW, while looking for the requested function I noticed that the division of command implementations by different source files doesn't strictly follow the scheme declared in the beginning of the two of them.

```
/*
 * tclCompCmds.c --
 *
 *  This file contains compilation procedures that compile various Tcl
 *  commands into a sequence of instructions ("bytecodes").
 *
 */

/*
 * tclCompCmdsGR.c --
 *
 *  This file contains compilation procedures that compile various Tcl
 *  commands (beginning with the letters 'g' through 'r') into a sequence
 *  of instructions ("bytecodes").
 *
 */

/*
 * tclCompCmdsSZ.c --
 *
 *  This file contains compilation procedures that compile various Tcl
 *  commands (beginning with the letters 's' through 'z', except for
 *  [upvar] and [variable]) into a sequence of instructions ("bytecodes").
 *  Also includes the operator command compilers.
 *
 */
```

**tclCompCmds.c** doesn't state that it contains only part of the command implementations, but the other two files suggest that it should contain commands whose names start with 'a' through 'f'. *However, as an exception, it also includes the implementation of the* `lmap` *command*.

**tclCompCmdsGR.c** states that it contains implementations of command starting with 'g' through 'r'. *However* `upvar` *and* `variable` *also belong to* **tclCompCmdsGR.c**, but that is explicitly stated in the last file **tclCompCmdsSZ.c**, which, apart from that exception, hosts commands starting with 's' through 'z', *as well as the* `::tcl::mathop::*` *commands*.

Comment: They're split up because otherwise they'd be ridiculously long files. There's literally no other reason, same as the main interpreted implementations are split over three files. (And there's bits in other places too.) Also, arguably the _implementation_ of `if` is actually in `tclExecute.c` which can evaluate expressions and do conditional jumps in bytecode…